# PHP SELECT acting strange

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with PHP and Mysql. PHP is acting very strange. This is my code

```
echo "<form action='scripts/leerling.php' method='post'>";
echo "Nieuwe Leerling: <br/><br/>";
echo "Naam<br/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='naam'/><br/><br/>";
echo "Leeftijd<br/><input type='number' name='leeftijd'/><br/><br/>";
echo "Ouder:<br/>";
echo "<select name='ouder'>";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE group=3");
while($record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
    echo "<option value='" . $record2["id"] . "'>" . $record2["username"] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select><br/> <br/>";
echo "<input type='image' src='img/plus.png'/><span style='font-size: 11pt;'> Leerling Toevoegen</span>";
echo "</form>";
```

i think everyting is allright. I want to make a selectbox with variable options. Now comes the annoying part: if i change this:`mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE group=3")` To this:`mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=3")` it works! and i dont know why... My table of my database sure has a column named `ID` AND a column named group and they are both the datatype `INT` but `ID` is also A_I. I dont know if that matters...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps because [GROUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) is a reserved word in MySQL? Try this:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'group' = 3" );
```